# how to access members from a class

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer, pyuic

im using QtDesigner which drops its code in a Class when converted to .py.

I have to access the buttons and labels and textboxes outside of the class to do operations on them. I cant put my functions above the class because of unresolved error. I dont want to add my functions inside the class.. theres alot of stuff and its messy. so i have to put my functions after the class.

here is a over simplified sample python code structure that Qt Designer converts to

```
class MyWindowUI():
    def setupUI(self):
        self.myButton1 = 'A'
        self.myButton2 = 'B'

    def stuff(self):
        self.myButton3 = 'A'
        self.myButton4 = 'B'
    test = "something"

myBtn = MyWindowUI()
print (myBtn.test)
print (myBtn.myButton4)
```

so, myBtn.test works. it prints 'something', but, myBtn.myButton4 doesnt. Says MyWindowUI instance has no attribute 'myButton4.

How do I get information from "stuff" and "setupUI" from outside the class?

Comment: Please read the PyQt documentation on this subject: [Using Qt Designer](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/designer.html).

Comment: Yes, I read. The actual .ui file conversation and the one in the docs don't match. That's why I'm asking. The converter script doesn't create a py script with __init__ even though, I specify the flags to do so. I'm over that though, onto other solutions.

Comment: You have misunderstood the documentation. The examples shown are scripts that you must create yourself. The module generated by `pyuic` should be imported into the script.

Comment: ohhhhh, i see.. that makes sense now. :) thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not calling methods, your code never enters those code blocks to create variables.

One way is calling them in `__init__` but you can call them anywhere you like after creating your class instance. Just be sure, your code goes through that line.

```
class MyWindowUI():
    def __init__(self):
        self.setupUI()
        self.stuff()

    def setupUI(self):
        self.myButton1 = 'A'
        self.myButton2 = 'B'

    def stuff(self):
        self.myButton3 = 'A'
        self.myButton4 = 'B'
    test = "something"

myBtn = MyWindowUI()
#myBtn.setupUI()
#myBtn.stuff()
print (myBtn.test)
print (myBtn.myButton4)
```

Comment: I'm fairly new to Qt. The script generator didn't add a __init__. I think if I add __init__ it will break the gui. I'll try when I get back to class in the morning. Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without adding __init__?

Comment: Commented two lines at the bottom. You can remove init and uncomment those two lines.